# IF statement behaving the opposite way

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I've written a little script that scans a text file in the below format.

[image]

Then outputs a different text file with the redirected URLs, only if there is a redirection. Otherwise, I wanted to print out "No redirection". But for some reason, the exact opposite happens.

Below is my code, could you please explain me what I did wrong?

```
import urllib.request

inc_input = input("Please enter the file name\n")
file_name = open(inc_input)
f = open('output.txt', 'w')
for line in file_name:
    eachurl = line.strip()
    redirected = urllib.request.urlopen(eachurl)
    finalurl = redirected.geturl()

    if eachurl == finalurl:
        f.write(eachurl + "\t" + finalurl + "\n")
    else:
        f.write(eachurl + "\t" + "No redirection" + "\n")
f.close()
```

Comment: If you include your test text as plain text, then we'd be able to test your code.

Comment: can you print `eachurl` and `finalurl` before testing? `strip()` is useful, but there may be other problems.

Comment: can u just try to print eachurl and finalurl and you will find your answer.

Comment: The logic in your code is wrong. You print `"No redirection"` if `eachurl` and `finalurl` differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic seems opposite to what you expect, I've added comments to clarify:

```
if eachurl == finalurl:
    # no redirection happened since we're in the original url (==)
    f.write(eachurl + "\t" + finalurl + "\n")
else:
    # redirection happened, different url
    f.write(eachurl + "\t" + "No redirection" + "\n")
```

Use `not` to reverse the condition or reverse the bodies. Currently the message is misleading.

Comment: Or `!=` instead of `==`

Answer (score 1):

```
if eachurl != finalurl:  #when the urls are not same, it's a redirection
    f.write(eachurl + "\t" + finalurl + "\n")
else:
    f.write(eachurl + "\t" + "No redirection" + "\n")
```

Comment: If you want to write the `if` this way round, it's more idiomatic to use `eachurl != finalurl`. In fact the first time I read your answer I didn't even see the `not` and got confused! But even then, I think it's better to swap the two clauses than to have a negative comparison in an `if` statement that has an `else` clause.